# How can I reference ForeignKey in django to populate a pedigree sheet?

Tags: python, django

I have two models that is linked each other by ForeignKey and OneToOneField as follows:

## Models

```
class Porumbei(models.Model):
    serie_inel = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, blank=False, unique=True,
                              help_text="Seria de pe inel. Ex: RO 123456")
    ...
    ...
    tata = models.ForeignKey('Perechi', to_field='mascul', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                         related_name="porumbei_masculi", null=True, blank=True)
    mama = models.ForeignKey('Perechi', to_field='femela', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                         related_name="porumbei_femele", null=True, blank=True)


class Perechi(models.Model):
    ...
    mascul = models.OneToOneField(Porumbei, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                  limit_choices_to=Q(sex="Mascul"), related_name="perechi_masculi")
    femela = models.OneToOneField(Porumbei, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                  limit_choices_to=Q(sex="Femelă"), related_name="perechi_femele")
    ...
```

In template I need to populate a table with ancestors of pigeons.
To retrieve the pigeon from database I use:

## Views

```
def editareporumbei(request, pk):
    porumbel = get_object_or_404(Porumbei, pk=pk)
```

Then, in ancestor table, at father field I use

```
{{ porumbel.tata.mascul }}
```

My question is how I can get the grandfather, grandgrandfather  of porumbel? How could I get it in template?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access them with

```
# For grand-father
porumbel.tata.mascul.tata.mascul
# For grand-grand-father
porumbel.tata.mascul.tata.mascul.tata.mascul
# and so on...
```